# View with elevation and shadow in ConstraintLayout

Tags: shadow, android-constraintlayout, android-elevation

How can I show elevations in a view with shadows using `ConstraintLayout`?

With `Relative` and `Linear` could perform elevations with shadows to implement list but I can not do it with `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_ssid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:text="SSID"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_ch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="CH"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_dB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="dB"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="239dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.83"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="306dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 23):

For some reason, elevation works in `ConstraintLayout` if you give a dummy drawable as the background::

Create a drawable:

dummyBg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Use this as the background for the view and  use elevation as you normally would.

```
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dummyBg"
    android:padding="4dp"
```

So you'd get:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_ssid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dummyBg"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="SSID"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Came here to solve a problem with shadows, turns out your example also shows how to round corners on the element, something I couldn't find an answer for as straight as yours. Thanks!

Comment: @JesusoOrtiz glad I could help (:

Comment: my exact requirement! Thx

Comment: Invisible container, change dummyGb.xml: <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
        </shape>

Answer (score 12):

In order to make elevation work, you need to **just set a background color** to a view.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/your_color"
    android:text="SSID"/>
```

Doesn't matter what kind of View it is,
a child of ConstraintLayout or ConstraintLayout itself

You also may use hex color or color attribute.
Just note that it mustn't be fully transparent.